# image in canvas is going to top left corner on some devices

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, model-viewer

I am trying to capture an image of a 3d foot model with the point where I click everything's working fine on some devices.
I am using this method to make an image

```
var img = new Image();
img.src = model.toDataURL;
img.width = 200;
img.height = 200;
```

and drawing this on a canvas context like this

```
img.onload = function () {
   ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,200,200);
}
```

on every device the image fits to the canvas but on 2,3 devices the image is in the top left corner or you can say in the 1st quadrant.

it should be like this
[Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1i6T.png)

but on some devices its like this
[Incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2uWT.png)

the point is perfectly drawn according to 200 x 200 canvas size